# Can one elect one's style/title of address in judicial proceedings?

Tags: england-and-wales, rules-of-court, litigation, name

If one wishes to be referred to as "Dr. Franklin," "Lord Jones" or "Lady Smith" (or Sir, or Dame) but does not actually possess the title, will judges use these titles in judicial proceedings? If so, can one extend elective titles of to "King Johnson" or "Queen Black"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There do not appear to be any specific judicial rules or legislation covering this, other than the common law principle that you can use whatever name pleases you provided it is not done with intent to deceive. Therefore, the use of elective titles seems be at the discretion of the judge.

It's unlikely that they would entertain the notion of using those titles unless properly held by the person in question, as there's no positive obligation on the judge to address the person by anything other than the title(s) they actually hold.